# PHP PDO & transactions - different behavior on PHP 5.4 and PHP 5.2.13

Tags: php, pdo, php-5.2

is there some significant difference between PHP 5.4 and 5.2.13 for the following code? It works with PHP 5.4 (& mysql 5.1.62), no error is shown and query is executed. However with 5.2.13 (& mysql 5.1.3.0) it doesn't show any error (it doesn't fall in to the catch block) but the data are not inserted into the database

```
 $db = new PDO(DHOST, DUSER, DPASS, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true));
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

 try {
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $db->exec($insertString);
        $db->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        try {
            $db->rollBack();
            throwDbError($handler->errorInfo());
        } catch (Exception $e2) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

If I ommit the lines with `beginTransaction` and `commit`, it works in PHP 5.2 as well but I need the transactions. Both tables in mysql databases are using InnoDB

Comment: The line `DB_DAO::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);` looks suspicious though. Is 5.4 using exception error mode perhaps?

Comment: sorry, old code fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error mode is not set to throw exceptions. Change:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
```

To:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

There should be no discernable difference between the two PHP versions.

Comment: Thanks, after that I got "PDO exception: Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active" . Don't know what's the difference but at least I've found the problem and made some workaround

Comment: Could be a difference in the mysqlclient libraries that it's linked to. Not sure, but I'm glad you found a workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

You should catch `PDOException`, not `Exception`.

Comment: All exception classes derive from Exception

Comment: @Narf although this might arguably be better, it doesn't address the problem found.